# Qt Creator: Getting error "skipping incompatible" when include library

Tags: qt

I'm using Qt Creator on Linux KDE. I'm about to include a library in my Qt project. The library is included with success, but I got the following errors:

```
    :-1: error: skipping incompatible /home/administrator/yyyyy/xxxxx/../../../../opt/QtSDK
/Madde/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/usr/lib//libcrypto.so when 
searching for -lcrypto (the following is in red colour) File not found: (which one isn't 
told)

    :-1: error: skipping incompatible /home/administrator/yyyyy/xxxxx/../../../../opt/QtSDK
/Madde/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/usr/lib//libcrypto.a when 
searching for -lcrypto (the following is in red colour) File not found: (which one isn't 
told)

    :-1: error: skipping incompatible /home/administrator/yyyyy/xxxxx/../../../../opt/QtSDK
/Madde/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/usr/lib//libpthread.so when 
searching for -lpthread (the following is in red colour) File not found: (which one isn't 
told)

    :-1: error: skipping incompatible /home/administrator/yyyyy/xxxxx/../../../../opt/QtSDK
/Madde/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/usr/lib//libpthread.a when 
searching for -lpthread File not found: (which one isn't told)

    :-1: error: skipping incompatible /home/administrator/yyyyy/xxxxx/../../../../opt/QtSDK
/Madde/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/usr/lib//libm.so when 
searching for -lm File not found: (which one isn't told)

    :-1: error: skipping incompatible /home/administrator/yyyyy/xxxxx/../../../../opt/QtSDK
/Madde/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/usr/lib//libm.a when searching 
for -lm File not found: (which one isn't told)

    :-1: error: skipping incompatible /home/administrator/yyyyy/xxxxx/../../../../opt/QtSDK
/Madde/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/usr/lib//libc.so when 
searching for -lc File not found: (which one isn't told)

    :-1: error: skipping incompatible /home/administrator/yyyyy/xxxxx/../../../../opt/QtSDK
/Madde/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/usr/lib//libc.a when searching 
for -lc File not found: (which one isn't told)
```

I added the libraries in the .pro-file using the "add library" function in Qt Creator and choosed "external library". I got the following code:

```
unix:!macx:!symbian: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../opt/QtSDK/Madde/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/usr/lib/ -lcrypto

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../opt/QtSDK/Madde/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/usr/include/openssl
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../opt/QtSDK/Madde/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/usr/include/openssl

unix:!macx:!symbian: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../opt/QtSDK/Madde/sysroots/harmattan-nokia-meego-arm-sysroot-1122-slim/usr/lib/libcrypto.a
```

Actually my programm works, but I don't understand what Qt is doing. It seem like Qt is trying to include other libraries with similar names - but why?

Answer (score 3):

It might be the case that you have both x64 and x86 libraries on your system, and in process of lookup the incompatible ones are skipped

Comment: This could be possible. (additionaly: I had some more "crypto" libraries in my folder - with a different ending (.so, ...)). I isolated crypto.a (the one i need). No I get only one error:
**:-1: error: skipping incompatible /home/administrator/yyyyy/xxxxx/../Library//libcrypto.a when searching for -lcrypto**.
Unfortunately this is the library I need - and strangely the one I use (the programm works).
Do you know how to find out more about the library?

Comment: Now, the folder containing the library only contains the library I need (libcrypto.a). How can this library be a x64 and x86 library?

Comment: First you can check what library the qt is actually using by looking into the Makefile generated. On the second question you can run "readelf -h libname.a". This will show you the library header and which arch it is built for.

Comment: Probably the problem is that the library is built for an ARM-Microcontroller: readelf -h librcrypto.a shows (among other things):  "Machine: ARM". In one or two weeks I can ask s.o. who has set up this library - so you doesn't need to answer anymore.